# NavigationStack in combination with a TabView (SwiftUI, iOS16)

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview, ios16, swiftui-navigationstack

What is the correct way to combine the mentioned views.

As of now, i have a `NavigationStack` at the bottom of my app. It displays a `LaunchView` as root. When a user is authenticated, the main view is added to the stack, if not, the login/ register views are added to the stack. This works fine.

```
NavigationStack(path: self.$vm.path) {
        LaunchView()
            .navigationDestination(for: Authentication.self) { value in
                switch value {
                    case .login:
                        LoginView(vm: LoginViewModel() { type, action in
                            ...
                        })
                    case .verify: // let .verify(email)
                        VerifyMailView(vm: VerifyMailViewModel() { type, action in
                            ...
                        })
                    case .authenticated:
                        AuthenticatedView() { type, action in
                            self.vm.set(type: type) { value in
                                ...
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        
    }
```

The `AuthenticatedView` consists of a `TabView` with three views. Here comes the issue. I assumed i could set the title and toolbars of the three views directly on them, which is not the case. However i don't want nor can set the titles or the toolbars within the tabview, as they require data from the views viewmodels (to which the `TabView` has, and should not have, no access).

```
TabView(selection: self.$vm.index) {
        DiscoverView(vm: DiscoverViewModel(account: self.vm.$account, type: self.type))
        .tabItem {
            Image(self.vm.index == 0 ? "discover.selected" : "discover")
        }
        .tag(0)
        
        MatchesView(vm: MatchesViewModel(type: self.type))
        .tabItem {
            Image(self.vm.index == 1 ? "matches.selected" : "matches")
        }
        .tag(1)
        
        ProfileView(vm: ProfileViewModel(account: self.vm.$account, type: self.type))
        .tabItem {
            Image(self.vm.index == 2 ? "profile.selected" : "profile")
        }
        .tag(2)
    }
    .toolbar(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
```

The only workaround i found is to hide the navigationbar in the `TabView` and to set new `NavigationView`s within the child views.

```
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ...
            }
            .navigationTitle(Text("discover"))
            .toolbar {
                ...
            }
        }
```

This, however, feels not correct as it is a NavigationView inside a NavigationView and even is buggy (the title and toolbar are sometimes placed below their *normal position*, kind of like below the hidden, but still exisiting navigation bar of the `TabView`).

Thus, has anyone found a solution of how to properly combine a `NavigationStack` with a `TabView` ?

Comment: A `TabView` cannot be inside a `NavigationStack` but each `tabItem` can have its own `NavigationStack`. This is in the apple guidelines. If you have a `TabView` it should always be visible. People can get around this by making their own but apple does not provide this functionality.

Comment: There is a difference between a `NavigationStack` and a `NavigationView`. You are saying that one can never use both, a `NavigationStack` and a `TabView`, within an app. This would mean you would miss out on programatic navigation if you were to implement a `TabView`, which does not make sense to me.

Comment: I didn’t say within an app I said that the navigation has to be in each tab not outside the tab view. Look up the tab bar design guidelines.

Comment: This is correct, however i am talking about a `NavigationStack` not a `NavigationView`. And it makes no sense to create multiple stacks for each tab, as there should only be one.

Comment: That is how apple wants it, it isn’t about making sense. You can circumvent this by making your own tab view which only takes a few lines of code.

Comment: @loremipsum where I can find this in the apple guidelines?

Comment: I add a link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162743/interacting-with-a-confirmationdialog-or-alert-is-causing-the-parent-view-to-pop/74163592#74163592)

Comment: @lr058 Did you find solution, i facing same issues with you.

Comment: There is no solution to the problem described. I ended up building my own navigation system.

Answer (score 4):

I found [lorem ipsum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12738750/lorem-ipsum)'s comments to be enlightening, so I built a sample app based on their ideas.

The following Swift code is an example for how a basic app can be built, where each page in a TabView has its own NavigationStack.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            AirplaneView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Airplane Tab", systemImage: "airplane.circle")
                }
            PlanetView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Planet Tab", systemImage: "globe.americas.fill")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct AirplaneView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Airplane tab view")
                Divider()
                NavigationLink(destination: NestedItemA()) {
                    Text("Go to nested airplane view")
                }
                .navigationTitle("Airplane")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PlanetView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Planet tab view")
                Divider()
                NavigationLink(destination: NestedItemB()) {
                    Text("Go to nested planet view")
                }
                .navigationTitle("Planet")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NestedItemA: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("Airplane goes vroom")
                .navigationTitle("Nested airplane")
        }
    }
}

struct NestedItemB: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("Planet spin good")
                .navigationTitle("Nested planet")
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an animated preview.

[image]

Comment: Let's say that I click "Go to nested airplane view" and I am obviously seeing NestedItemA View. But now I'd like click on AirplaneIcon in TabView to navigate to AirplaneView. Currently I need to click back button to achieve that?