# Navigation Title not showing if View inside TabView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a content view like below. I add a FirstView that has tab view inside of it pointing to 2 separate view. however my problem is the NavigationTitle just does not show up no matter what I do, is it normal or an error on my part

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var data: DataController
    var body: some View {
             FirstView(dataController: data)
  }
}
```

Then the First View has 2 tab items inside TabView

```
import SwiftUI

struct FirstView: View {
    @ObservedObject var dataController: DataController
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            TabView {
               
                MyAdsPageView(dataAd: dataController)
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                        }
                
                ListPageView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("List", systemImage: "list.bullet")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But my problem is not matter what I try , I cannot seem to show Navigation Title inside. the MyAdsPageView

```
struct MyAdsPageView: View {
   
    @ObservedObject var dataAd: DataController
   
    var body: some View {
       
            NavigationStack {
                
                    List {
                    }
                    .navigationTitle("My List")
    }
}
```

Comment: The navigation stack has to be for each tab inside the tab view not outside

Comment: Thanks so much that was perfect, any chance you can name a resource for navigation in swiftui, especially with navigation stack , I am having a real hard time managing tab view, toolbar and back buttons and all that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interacting with a confirmationDialog or alert is causing the parent view to pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162743/interacting-with-a-confirmationdialog-or-alert-is-causing-the-parent-view-to-pop)

Comment: The human interface guidelines “explain” why the stack outside is an issue. I elaborate a little on the link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make navigation inside each tab view. Your code will create a nested NavigationView and app will confuse to set the title for it. And it is good to have tags for each tab. use it in this way:

```
struct FirstView: View {
@ObservedObject var dataController: DataController
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        
        MyAdsPageView(dataAd: dataController)
            .tabItem {
                Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
            }
            .tag(0)
        
        ListPageView()
            .tabItem {
                Label("List", systemImage: "list.bullet")
            }
            .tag(1)
    }
    
  }
}

  struct ListPageView: View {
        var body: some View {
            NavigationStack {
                ZStack {
                    
                }
                .navigationTitle("My List")
            }
        }
    }


 struct MyAdsPageView: View {
        var body: some View {
            NavigationStack {
                ZStack {
                    
                }
                .navigationTitle("My Ads")
            }
        }
    }
```