# Initial Tab Does not show in TabView

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I am trying to create a simple TabView in the Left panel of a SwiftUI NavigationView.  The first Tab does not show up in the TabView menu, but it shows as the initial view with the app is launched.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    
    @State var listView: ListView = ListView.recipients
    @State var addItem = false
    @State private var searchString = ""
    @State var selectedTab = 0
    @Query private var recipients: [Recipient]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                FilteredList(searchString: searchString, listView: .recipients)
                    .tag(0)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Recipient", systemImage: "person.crop.circle")
                    }
                FilteredList(searchString: searchString, listView: .events)
                    .tag(1)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Event", systemImage: "calendar.circle")
                    }
                FilteredList(searchString: searchString, listView: .greetingCard)
                    .tag(2)
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Gallery", systemImage: "photo.circle")
                    }
            }
            Text("Make a selection")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.green)
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.automatic)
    }
}
```

On the iPhone it shows correctly, but on the iPad the first tab is missing:

[image: iPhone View]
[image: iPad View]

Comment: maybe this post would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61970939/swiftui-hide-tabview-bar-inside-navigationlink-views

Comment: Actually the issue is only on the iPad on the iPhone all three tabs show fine.  It's almost like the width of the tabItems is too wide.

Comment: Added pictures - hope that clarifies the issue.

Comment: see also post dealing with: [TabView inside a NavigstionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74162743/interacting-with-a-confirmationdialog-or-alert-is-causing-the-parent-view-to-pop/74163592#74163592)

Comment: Looking at Apple’s UX design guidelines, it may just be a sizing issue.  I will adjust text and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up redesigning the View to the following code:

```
 var body: some View {
    TabView(selection: $listView) {
        NavigationView {
            FilteredList(searchText: searchText, listView: .events, navigationPath: $navigationPath)
                .searchable(text: $searchText)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                            Text("Events")
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button(action: {
                            listView = .events
                            self.addItem.toggle()
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                                .font(.title2)
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                        })
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        EditButton()
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                    }
                }
        }
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "calendar")
            Text("Events")
                .foregroundColor(.green)
        }
        .tag(ListView.events)
        NavigationView {
            FilteredList(searchText: searchText, listView: .greetingCard, navigationPath: $navigationPath)
                .searchable(text: $searchText)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                            Text("Gallery")
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button(action: {
                            listView = .greetingCard
                            self.addItem.toggle()
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                                .font(.title2)
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                        })
                    }
                }
        }
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "photo.stack")
            Text("Gallery")
                .foregroundColor(.green)
        }
        .tag(ListView.greetingCard)
        NavigationView {
            FilteredList(searchText: searchText, listView: .recipients, navigationPath: $navigationPath)
                .searchable(text: $searchText)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                            Text("Recipient")
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button(action: {
                            listView = .recipients
                            self.addItem.toggle()
                        }, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                                .font(.title2)
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                        })
                    }
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        EditButton()
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                    }
                }
        }
        .tabItem {
            Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
            Text("Receipients")
                .foregroundColor(.green)
        }
        .tag(ListView.recipients)
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $addItem) {
        switch listView {
        case .events:
            NewEventView()
        case .recipients:
            NewRecipientView()
        case .greetingCard:
            NewGreetingCardView()
        }
    }
}
```

This is is working much more appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the first tab is hidden on the left, so if you slide the split view to the right, you may see it. The workaround I found is to add a "dummy" first tab; doing that "pushes" the 2nd tab to the right, making it visible.