# Simple SwiftUI View bug when using header UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, view, header

I am making a simple view with content in a scroll view and a top header. When the user scrolls down I want to hide the header and when the user scrolls up I want to show it. I have three different tabs and if I manually swipe between them everything works fine. If I try and click the buttons in the header to switch tabs the scroll view adjusts the scroll view a bit and does nothing then I get a ton of the error below.

**The code works when (either or)**

1. removing *.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)* fixes the problem
2. Removing the TabView and using conditional rendering to show the tabs.

I want to retain the functionality of both the ignore safe are and tabview, how can I workaround this?

*The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because: the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values*

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct FeedViewSec: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @State private var selection = 0
    @State var headerHeight: CGFloat = 130
    @State var headerOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State var lastHeaderOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State var direction: SwipeDirection = .none
    @State var shiftOffset: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing){
                TabView(selection: $selection) {
                    scrollBody().tag(0)
                    scrollBody().tag(1)
                    scrollBody().tag(2)
                }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                headerView().offset(y: -headerOffset < headerHeight ? headerOffset : (headerOffset < 0 ? headerOffset : 0))
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
        }
    }
    func scrollBody() -> some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVStack {
                Color.clear.frame(height: 130)
                ForEach(0..<30){ i in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                }
            }
            .offsetY { previous, current in
                if previous > current {
                    if direction != .up && current < 0{
                        shiftOffset = current - headerOffset
                        direction = .up
                        lastHeaderOffset = headerOffset
                    }
                    
                    let offset = current < 0 ? (current - shiftOffset) : 0

                    headerOffset = (-offset < headerHeight ? (offset < 0 ? offset : 0) : -headerHeight * 2.0)
                } else {
                    if direction != .down{
                        shiftOffset = current
                        direction = .down
                        lastHeaderOffset = headerOffset
                    }
                    
                    let offset = lastHeaderOffset + (current - shiftOffset)
                    headerOffset = (offset > 0 ? 0 : offset)
                }
            }
        }.coordinateSpace(name: "SCROLL")
    }
    func headerView() -> some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            HStack {
                HStack(spacing: 1){
                    Text("Explore").font(.title).bold()
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.down").font(.body).bold()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.leading)
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut){
                        selection = 0
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("New")
                        .foregroundColor(.black).bold()
                        .frame(width: 80, height: 25)
                }
                .background((selection == 0) ? colorScheme == .dark ? .gray.opacity(0.3) : .gray : colorScheme == .dark ? .gray : .gray.opacity(0.3))
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut){
                        selection = 1
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("LeaderBoard")
                        .foregroundColor(.black).bold()
                        .frame(width: 120, height: 25)
                }
                .background((selection == 1) ? colorScheme == .dark ? .gray.opacity(0.3) : .gray : colorScheme == .dark ? .gray : .gray.opacity(0.3))
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut){
                        selection = 2
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Hot")
                        .foregroundColor(.black).bold()
                        .frame(width: 80, height: 25)
                }
                .background((selection == 2) ? colorScheme == .dark ? .gray.opacity(0.3) : .gray : colorScheme == .dark ? .gray : .gray.opacity(0.3))
            }
            .mask {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
            }
            .padding(.top, 8)
            Color.clear.frame(height: 13)
        }
        .padding(.top, top_Inset())
        .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
    }
}

func top_Inset() -> CGFloat {
    let scenes = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    let windowScene = scenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    let window = windowScene?.windows.first
    
    return window?.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0
}
extension View{
    @ViewBuilder
    func offsetY(completion: @escaping (CGFloat,CGFloat)->())->some View{
        self.modifier(OffsetHelper(onChange: completion))
    }
    func safeArea()->UIEdgeInsets{
        guard let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else{return .zero}
        guard let safeArea = scene.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets else{return .zero}
        return safeArea
    }
}
struct OffsetHelper: ViewModifier{
    var onChange: (CGFloat,CGFloat)->()
    @State var currentOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State var previousOffset: CGFloat = 0
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay {
                GeometryReader{proxy in
                    let minY = proxy.frame(in: .named("SCROLL")).minY
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(key: OffsetKeyNew.self, value: minY)
                        .onPreferenceChange(OffsetKeyNew.self) { value in
                            previousOffset = currentOffset
                            currentOffset = value
                            onChange(previousOffset,currentOffset)
                        }
                }
            }
    }
}
struct OffsetKeyNew: PreferenceKey{
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
struct HeaderBoundsKey: PreferenceKey{
    static var defaultValue: Anchor<CGRect>?
    
    static func reduce(value: inout Anchor<CGRect>?, nextValue: () -> Anchor<CGRect>?) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
enum SwipeDirection{
    case up
    case down
    case none
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the complete working solution done by KavSoft. I recommend everyone checking out his YouTube, it's great.

```
import SwiftUI

struct FeedViewSec: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @State private var selection = 0
    @State var headerHeight: CGFloat = 130
    @State var headerOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State var lastHeaderOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State var direction: SwipeDirection = .none
    @State var shiftOffset: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView(.init()){
                TabView(selection: $selection) {
                    scrollBody().tag(0)
                    scrollBody().tag(1)
                    scrollBody().tag(2)
                }
                .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
                .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                    headerView()
                        .offset(y: -headerOffset < headerHeight ? headerOffset : (headerOffset < 0 ? headerOffset : 0))
                }
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func scrollBody() -> some View {
        ScrollView {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(.clear)
                .frame(height: 90 + top_Inset())
                .offsetY { previous, current in
                    if previous > current {
                        if direction != .up && current < 0{
                            shiftOffset = current - headerOffset
                            direction = .up
                            lastHeaderOffset = headerOffset
                        }
                        
                        let offset = current < 0 ? (current - shiftOffset) : 0

                        headerOffset = (-offset < headerHeight ? (offset < 0 ? offset : 0) : -headerHeight * 2.0)
                    } else {
                        if direction != .down{
                            shiftOffset = current
                            direction = .down
                            lastHeaderOffset = headerOffset
                        }
                        
                        let offset = lastHeaderOffset + (current - shiftOffset)
                        headerOffset = (offset > 0 ? 0 : offset)
                    }
                }
            
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(0..<30){ i in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                }
            }
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: "SCROLL")
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func headerView() -> some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            HStack {
                HStack(spacing: 1){
                    Text("Explore").font(.title).bold()
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.down").font(.body).bold()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.leading)
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut){
                        selection = 0
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("New")
                        .foregroundColor(.black).bold()
                        .frame(width: 80, height: 25)
                }
                .background((selection == 0) ? colorScheme == .dark ? .gray.opacity(0.3) : .gray : colorScheme == .dark ? .gray : .gray.opacity(0.3))
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut){
                        selection = 1
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("LeaderBoard")
                        .foregroundColor(.black).bold()
                        .frame(width: 120, height: 25)
                }
                .background((selection == 1) ? colorScheme == .dark ? .gray.opacity(0.3) : .gray : colorScheme == .dark ? .gray : .gray.opacity(0.3))
                Button {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut){
                        selection = 2
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Hot")
                        .foregroundColor(.black).bold()
                        .frame(width: 80, height: 25)
                }
                .background((selection == 2) ? colorScheme == .dark ? .gray.opacity(0.3) : .gray : colorScheme == .dark ? .gray : .gray.opacity(0.3))
            }
            .mask {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
            }
            .padding(.top, 8)
        }
        .frame(height: 90)
        .padding(.top, top_Inset())
        .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
    }
}


extension View{
    @ViewBuilder
    func offsetY(completion: @escaping (CGFloat,CGFloat)->())->some View{
        self.modifier(OffsetHelper(onChange: completion))
    }
    func safeArea()->UIEdgeInsets{
        guard let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene else{return .zero}
        guard let safeArea = scene.windows.first?.safeAreaInsets else{return .zero}
        return safeArea
    }
}
struct OffsetHelper: ViewModifier{
    var onChange: (CGFloat,CGFloat)->()
    @State var currentOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State var previousOffset: CGFloat = 0
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay {
                GeometryReader{proxy in
                    let minY = proxy.frame(in: .named("SCROLL")).minY
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(key: OffsetKeyNew.self, value: minY)
                        .onPreferenceChange(OffsetKeyNew.self) { value in
                            previousOffset = currentOffset
                            currentOffset = value
                            onChange(previousOffset,currentOffset)
                        }
                }
            }
    }
}
struct OffsetKeyNew: PreferenceKey{
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
struct HeaderBoundsKey: PreferenceKey{
    static var defaultValue: Anchor<CGRect>?
    
    static func reduce(value: inout Anchor<CGRect>?, nextValue: () -> Anchor<CGRect>?) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
enum SwipeDirection{
    case up
    case down
    case none
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be a simpler way to achieve the effect you're after. In the revised example below, the following techniques are used:

- Each `ScrollView` has a `GeometryReader` in the background and this is used to monitor for a change of scroll position.
- Instead of attempting to set a precise offset on the header, the header is either fully visible or fully hidden, with changes animated.
- The height of the header is read using a `GeometryReader` in `.onAppear`. By placing the `.ignoresSafeArea` more selectively, it is not necessary to add padding to compensate for the safe area insets.
- Whenever the tab selection changes, the new tab is automatically scrolled to the top using a `ScrollViewPoxy`.  The header is also brought into view, if it was previously hidden.
- I found that the bounce effect of the `ScrollView` was causing the header to be hidden or to become visible when it was not supposed to. To prevent this from happening, a change of scroll direction is only accepted if there has been a delay of at least 0.5s since the last scroll.
- This is a pure SwiftUI solution, no UI classes are used, nor are any values written to the preferences.

Here you go:

```swift
struct FeedViewSec: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @State private var selection = 0
    @State var isHeaderHidden = false
    @State var headerHeight: CGFloat = 0
    @State var referenceScrollOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State var direction: SwipeDirection = .none
    @State var timeOfLastScroll = Date.now

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing){
            TabView(selection: $selection) {
                scrollBody().tag(0)
                scrollBody().tag(1)
                scrollBody().tag(2)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .top) {
            headerView
                .offset(y: isHeaderHidden ? -headerHeight : 0)
                .animation(.easeInOut, value: isHeaderHidden)
        }
    }

    func scrollBody() -> some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                Color.clear
                    .frame(height: 130)
                    .id("top")
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(0..<30){ i in
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.top)
                .background(alignment: .top) {
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.clear

                            // pre iOS 17:
                            //.onChange(of: proxy.frame(in: .global).minY) { [oldMinY = proxy.frame(in: .global).minY] newMinY in
                            .onChange(of: proxy.frame(in: .global).minY) { oldMinY, newMinY in
                                if newMinY < oldMinY {

                                    // Scrolling up
                                    if direction != .up && timeOfLastScroll.timeIntervalSinceNow < -0.5 {
                                        referenceScrollOffset = oldMinY
                                        direction = .up
                                    }
                                    if referenceScrollOffset - newMinY > headerHeight / 2 {
                                        isHeaderHidden = true
                                    }
                                } else if newMinY > oldMinY {

                                    // Scrolling down
                                    if direction != .down && timeOfLastScroll.timeIntervalSinceNow < -0.5 {
                                        referenceScrollOffset = oldMinY
                                        direction = .down
                                    }
                                    if newMinY - referenceScrollOffset > headerHeight / 2 {
                                        isHeaderHidden = false
                                    }
                                }
                                timeOfLastScroll = Date.now
                            }
                    }
                    .frame(height: 1)
                }
                .onAppear {
                    proxy.scrollTo("top", anchor: .top)
                    timeOfLastScroll = Date.now
                    isHeaderHidden = false
                    direction = .none
                }
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }

    var headerView: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            // content as before
        }
//        .padding(.top, top_Inset())
        .background(
            GeometryReader { proxy in
                Color.clear
                    .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                    .onAppear {
                        if headerHeight == 0 {
                            headerHeight = proxy.frame(in: .global).maxY
                        }
                    }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: Hm, works fine for me on an iPhone 14 simulator running iOS 17, no errors at all in the console (at least, not since my last update a couple of hours ago). Have you tried a complete replacement of the previous example code with the code I posted, including deletion of all the redundant parts (the view modifiers and extensions)? The only part missing from what I posted was the enum ```SwipeDirection``` (which stays unchanged) and the main body of ```headerView``` (also unchanged, as indicated by the comment in code). Otherwise, what I posted is complete and can be copy/pasted for testing.

Comment: OK, I created a brand new Xcode project, deployment target iOS 16.0. I copy/pasted the code from my answer and supplemented it with the enum ```SwipeDirection``` from your original post, plus the contents of the ```VStack``` in the function ```headerView```, as explained in my previous comment. The only change needed was to switch the ```.onChange``` callback to the commented version for pre iOS 17.0 that was provided in the answer. I then ran on an iPhone 14 simulator running iOS 16.4 -> works fine, with no errors at all in console.

Comment: I updated to the newest Xcode, tried on IOS 17 and 16, on iPhone 14 and 15. And your solution doesn't work when switching tabs using the header buttons. Not sure how this is working for you. Would you be able to test my original solution and try and get it to work.

Comment: I revised the question and code, would you possibly know what's causing this now? Id appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: This puts a completely new perspective on the problem. A ```NavigationStack``` was not included in the original question. And I suppose, every time you were trying the solution provided, you were not testing it in the same form as it was provided. When it comes to ```TabView``` and ```NavigationStack``` in combination, a ```TabView``` may contain a ```NavigationStack```, _**but not the other way around**_ - see [NavigationStack in combination with a TabView (SwiftUI, iOS16)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73671138/20386264). So unfortunately, you probably need to re-think your hierarchy.

Comment: Ive reviewed the link you included. NavigationStack isn't the cause of the problem. I can take It out or put it anywhere else as the link mentions, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Removing the ignore safe area fixes the problem, but also removing the tab view and conditionally rendering the current view also fixes the issue.

Comment: Ive moved the question here as this will solve my problem, or maybe you know a different workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77268736/create-custom-tabview-swift-ui

Answer (score 0):

Tou have an error from the [`UICollectionViewFlowLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewflowlayout) which is related to the height of the items in the collection view.
However, you are using SwiftUI for your interface and not [UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit)'s [`UICollectionView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview). The error should mean that the item height in a collection view is too tall for the available space. It could be related to how SwiftUI is being bridged to UIKit under the hood, or how the UIKit's [`UIScrollView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview) is being managed within SwiftUI's [`ScrollView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollview).

You are trying to manage the header's visibility and the tab selection with quite a complex setup using offsets, preferences, and geometry readers. That setup might be making it hard to debug or identify the actual issue.

I would recommend first to simplify the layout: Temporarily remove the header and see if the error persists. That can help isolate whether the header is the cause of the issue. You might want to simplify the layout to the bare minimum to see if the error still occurs, and then gradually reintroduce elements to identify the cause.

Then check the layout calculations: Verify all the offset and height calculations, especially where you are manipulating `headerOffset` and `shiftOffset`, to ensure they are producing the intended values.

You might want to add some print statements or use a debugger to check the values of your offsets and other variables at runtime to see if anything unexpected is happening. The error message suggests setting a symbolic breakpoint at `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes` to catch this in the debugger. That might provide more insight into the issue.

---

> I have filtered it down to the following `code NavigationStack { FeedViewSec()//.ignoresSafeArea() }`: if I remove the `ignoreSafeArea` everything works just fine, if I add it then the tabs won't switch on button click.
> But I want the ignore safe area so that my view can be full screen.

Instead of using `.ignoresSafeArea()`, you might consider using the `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(:)` modifier with the appropriate edges specified. That could potentially avoid the issue you are facing with tab switching.

```swift
NavigationStack {
    FeedViewSec().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

Also, sometimes the order of views within a `ZStack` can cause issues with touch handling. Make sure the `TabView` and the header overlay are in the correct order so that the buttons in the header are receiving touches correctly.

And check the buttons within the header are explicitly bringing the desired tab to the front. It seems you are doing this with the `selection` state variable, which is good. But ensure that there is nothing else in your code that might be interfering with these actions.

---

> `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` will be depreciated and doesn't make a difference.

Given the fact that the buttons are being clicked correctly, yet the desired action is not being carried out as expected when `.ignoresSafeArea()` is used, that indicates that there might be a layout or rendering issue.

Since `.ignoresSafeArea()` is causing issues, you might want to explore alternative methods to achieve a full-screen view.

For instance, checking if there are new or updated modifiers in the latest version of SwiftUI that do full-screen layouts without interfering with the functionality.

You might consider creating a custom modifier to handle full-screen layout as a workaround. It may provide a way to control the layout more precisely and avoid the issues associated with `.ignoresSafeArea()`.

If SwiftUI continues to present limitations, consider using [`UIViewRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable/) to wrap a [`UIViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/) or [`UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/) that handles the full-screen layout and tab switching. That approach allows for more control and might bypass the issue you are encountering in SwiftUI.

---

> The TabView is what is causing the issue, removing that fixes it.

Then a custom TabView might be needed.

Comment: @ahmed I have edited the answer to address your comment and make some suggestions.

Comment: @ahmed OK, I have edited the answer to address your last comment.

Comment: The TabView is what is causing the issue, removing that fixes it, but I still want the tabviews features. Ive moved the question here as this will solve my problem, or maybe you know a different workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77268736/create-custom-tabview-swift-ui

Comment: @ahmed OK. I have included your current conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Von Ive moved the question about files here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77284789/swift-uploading-file-to-firestore-storage-then-trying-to-save-not-working