# Uploading file to Firebase storage then trying to save not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-storage

I am using Swift and I'm uploading a file from my local device to fire store storage in the formate of just raw bits. The upload works and I see the document in the database along with the correct size of the file.

Now with the location of the document in Firestore (URL) I try and download the file to my local device, I would like the file to appear in the iOS 'Files' application under downloads. When I click to download it everything runs good with no errors, however the file doesn't appear in "Files". If I take the url for the location of the file and paste it into Google, the file automatically downloads through google.

When I inspect the files app I can now see the download. When I click on it all that is displayed is the document ID along with the byte size. If I inspect it on my Mac then the file looks like below. I know I'm downloading the file wrong since it doesn't appear in the app. But am I also uploading it wrong since I can't view the real text?

[image: this].

```
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage

struct FilePicker: View {
   @State private var showPicker = false
   //for the sake of this example this is the url for a pdf doc stored in firestore storage
   @State private var finalURL: String? = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/hustle-85b6c.appspot.com/o/files%2FF425B036-D3DC-4B8A-9CE0-D7A8893D5466?alt=media&token=5a33534d-ea81-45c2-8113-042a9d021d05"
   
   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           Spacer()
           if let url = finalURL {
               Button(action: {
                   downloadFile(urlS: url)
               }, label: {
                   Text("download")
               })
           }
           
           Button(action: {
               showPicker.toggle()
           }, label: {
               Image(systemName: "paperclip")
                   .padding()
                   .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                   .background(.gray)
                   .clipShape(Circle())
           })
           Spacer()
       }
       .fileImporter(isPresented: $showPicker, allowedContentTypes: [UTType.data]) { result in
           do {
               let url = try result.get()
               let accessing = url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
               defer {
                   if accessing {
                       url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                   }
               }
               
               if let fileData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                   uploadFile(data: fileData, location: "files") { urlS in
                       print(urlS)
                       finalURL = urlS
                   }
               }
           } catch {
               print("File picker error: \(error)")
           }
       }
   }
   func downloadFile(urlS: String) {
       guard let url = URL(string: urlS) else {
           return
       }
       let downloadTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
           if let error = error {
               print("Error downloading file: \(error)")
               return
           }
           if let data = data {
               saveFile(data: data, fileName: "download\(UUID().uuidString.prefix(5))")
           }
       }
       downloadTask.resume()
   }
   func saveFile(data: Data, fileName: String) {
       guard let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
           return
       }
       
       let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
       
       do {
           try data.write(to: fileURL)
           print("File saved")
       } catch {
           print("Error saving file: \(error)")
       }
   }
   func uploadFile(data: Data, location: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
       let ref = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "/\(location)/\(NSUUID().uuidString)")

       ref.putData(data, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
           if let err = error {
               print(err)
           }
           ref.downloadURL { (url, error) in
               guard let downloadURL = url?.absoluteString else {
                   completion("")
                   return
               }
               completion(downloadURL)
           }
       }
   }
}
```

**Updated Save Func**

```
    func saveFile(data: Data, fileName: String, fileExtension: String) {
        guard let downloadsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
            return
        }
        let fileURL = downloadsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).\(fileExtension)")
        do {
            if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
                FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: fileURL.path, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
            }
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
            print("File saved")
        } catch {
            print("Error saving file: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: @KJ so the file was corrupted as it was uploaded to the db. Ive reviewed firestores documentation and it seems like im uploading it right. How do you propose I fix it?

Comment: The download of the file (23487 bytes) seems to work for me, and when I open the file on my Mac (added the `.pdf` extension),
 I get the `Hustles fix/add ....`.
 On MacOS 14.1, Xcode 15.1, tested on MacCatalyst.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine that's a relief, when I add the .pdf extension it works too! So now I guess I have to inspect the url of the file in my directory before uploading to my db in order to extract the file type. And then I can assign the document id to UUID() + file extension. I feel like this is a poor method, do you know better approaches?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are talking about, but `url.lastPathComponent` gives you
 the file **plus** the file extension, and `url.pathExtension` gives you **just** the file extention. Note it is best to remove/cancel your token from your`finalURL`, although it was very useful to test your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you can extract the file extension from the URL when uploading and downloading files, with `url.pathExtension` and  `url.lastPathComponent`.
That will be useful for preserving the file extension during the upload and download processes.
And make sure to append the correct file extension when saving the file.
As usual, adding error handling will help you identify and fix any issues.

For instance:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage

struct FilePicker: View {
    @State private var showPicker = false
    @State private var finalURL: String? = nil  // Initialize with nil, will be updated after upload
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            if let url = finalURL {
                Button(action: {
                    downloadFile(urlS: url)
                }, label: {
                    Text("Download")
                })
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                showPicker.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "paperclip")
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                    .background(.gray)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            })
            Spacer()
        }
        .fileImporter(isPresented: $showPicker, allowedContentTypes: [UTType.data]) { result in
            do {
                let url = try result.get()
                let accessing = url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                defer {
                    if accessing {
                        url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                    }
                }
                
                if let fileData = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                    // Extract file extension for preserving it during upload
                    let fileExtension = url.pathExtension  
                    uploadFile(data: fileData, location: "files", fileExtension: fileExtension) { urlS in
                        print(urlS)
                        finalURL = urlS
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print("File picker error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func downloadFile(urlS: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlS) else {
            return
        }
        let downloadTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            // Enhanced error handling
            if let error = error {
                print("Error downloading file: \(error)")
                return
            }
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                print("Error: Invalid HTTP response")
                return
            }
            // Extract file extension from download URL
            let fileExtension = url.pathExtension  
            if let data = data {
                saveFile(data: data, fileName: "download\(UUID().uuidString.prefix(5))", fileExtension: fileExtension)
            }
        }
        downloadTask.resume()
    }
    
    func saveFile(data: Data, fileName: String, fileExtension: String) {
        // Saving to Downloads directory
        guard let downloadsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
            return
        }
        let fileURL = downloadsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).\(fileExtension)")
        
        do {
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
            print("File saved")
        } catch {
            print("Error saving file: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func uploadFile(data: Data, location: String, fileExtension: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        let ref = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "/\(location)/\(NSUUID().uuidString).\(fileExtension)")
        ref.putData(data, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
            if let err = error {
                print(err)
            }
            ref.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                guard let downloadURL = url?.absoluteString else {
                    completion("")
                    return
                }
                // Save file metadata to Firestore
                saveFileMetadata(fileName: ref.name, fileExtension: fileExtension, downloadURL: downloadURL)
                completion(downloadURL)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func saveFileMetadata(fileName: String, fileExtension: String, downloadURL: String) {
        // Saving metadata to Firestore
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("fileMetadata").document(fileName).setData([
            "fileExtension": fileExtension,
            "downloadURL": downloadURL
        ]) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error saving metadata: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Metadata saved successfully")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That way:

- The file extension is extracted from the original file URL and preserved during the upload and download processes.
- Enhanced error handling has been added to the `downloadFile` function.
- The `saveFile` function has been updated to save the file to the Downloads directory, and the correct file extension is appended to the file name.
- The `uploadFile` function now includes the file extension when creating the Firebase storage reference.
- A new function `saveFileMetadata` has been added to save file metadata to a Firestore collection.

---

> I still get the same error in the save function "Error saving file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “download270DD.pdf” doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BF2761CF-A0C7-423D-B2A0-723A1A1820FB/Downloads/download270DD.pdf, NSUnderlyingError=0x283361080 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}"

If the `Downloads` directory may not be a valid or accessible directory on iOS, you might modify the `saveFile` function to save to the `Documents` directory instead:

```swift
func saveFile(data: Data, fileName: String, fileExtension: String) {
    // Get the app's Documents directory
    guard let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else {
        return
    }
    // Construct the full file URL
    let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).\(fileExtension)")
    
    do {
        // Write the data to the file URL
        try data.write(to: fileURL)
        print("File saved: \(fileURL)")
    } catch {
        // Handle any errors
        print("Error saving file: \(error)")
    }
}
```

The `FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first` method is used to get the URL of the app's `Documents` directory. The `fileURL` is constructed by appending the `fileName` and `fileExtension` to the `Documents` directory URL. The `data.write(to: fileURL)` method is used to write the data to the file.

Comment: Hey thanks once again. I still get the same error in the save function "Error saving file: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “download270DD.pdf” doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/BF2761CF-A0C7-423D-B2A0-723A1A1820FB/Downloads/download270DD.pdf, NSUnderlyingError=0x283361080 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}" I think there needs to be a file at the location for the write to happen. I tried creating a file before writing to it as seen in my update. I still get the same error. Maybe the path is wrong?

Comment: @ahmed I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I spent a few hours trying to debug and test different approaches. For some reason the code runs good with no errors but the file doesn't download. I can't find it anywhere in the files app. Did this work for you?

Comment: @ahmed I don't have access to a Mac right now to test it: my last edit was more about the fact `Documents` is more likely to be available.

Comment: Hey von would you look at this GitHub repo. Im adding it to my app, the repo has a few bugs and I tried to go through it and fix them but had no luck. Maybe you can give me some pointers, or maybe you know a better way to parse strings for code blocks. The relevant code is in Share > MarkdownAttributedStringParser.swift. Here's the link to it: https://github.com/alfianlosari/ChatGPTSwiftUI/issues/16